# Trocar imagem ao descer pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como troco o SRC da imagem (Com JQuery) ao descer a página e o scroll for maior que 10?

Trocar o

```
<img src="imagem_1.png" alt="Meu site">
```

pelo

```
<img src="imagem_2.png" alt="Meu site">
```

E depois ele voltar pra

```
<img src="imagem_1.png" alt="Meu site">
```

quando o scroll for menor que 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com **jquery**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 10) {
        $('img').attr('src', 'imagem_2.png');
    } else {
        $('img').attr('src', 'imagem_1.png');
    }
});
```

Com **JS** puro

```
var onScrollHandler = function() {
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= 10) {
     seuElemento.src = "imagem2.png"
  }else{
     seuElemento.src = "imagem1.png"
  }
};
object.addEventListener ("scroll", onScrollHandler);
```

*Nota que com javascript o `seuElemento` tem que ser substituído pelo elemento que tu quer adicionar a imagem, no caso sugiro você a colocar um id na sua `img`
e utilizar o método [`getElementById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) passando o id que foi atribuído.

Comment: Muito obrigado!